# Why am I unable to load scripts in head in plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, wp-enqueue-script

I have registered scripts which are supposed to load in head section. But for some reason I don't get these links loaded in head. Instead of loading scripts in head these are loading in footer.

```
 add_action('init', 'my_enqueued_assets');

    function my_enqueued_assets() { 
        //Register Css
        wp_register_style('my-css', MY_PLUGIN_URL.'css/my_styles.css'); 
        wp_register_style('my-admin-css', MY_PLUGIN_URL.'css/my_admin_styles.css'); 
        //Register JS 
        wp_register_script('my-jquery-min', MY_PLUGIN_URL.'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
        wp_register_script('my-script-min', MY_PLUGIN_URL.'js/my_isotope.min.js');
        wp_register_script('my-script', MY_PLUGIN_URL.'js/my_isotope.js', array('jquery'), my_PLUGIN_VERSION, false );
        wp_register_script('my-lightbox-script', MY_PLUGIN_URL.'js/my-lightbox.js', array('jquery'), my_PLUGIN_VERSION, false );
        wp_register_script('my-prefix-script',MY_PLUGIN_URL.'/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '0.1',false );
    }
```

I loaded these scripts in shortcode to load scripts and style when only shortcode is used or called.

```
function my_shortcodes_init()
{
    function my_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
    {
        //default portfolio value
        $id = 1;
        wp_enqueue_style('my-css'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('my-jquery-min');
        wp_enqueue_script('my-script-min'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('my-script');
        wp_enqueue_script('my-lightbox-script');

        if (isset($atts["id"])) {
            $id = $atts["id"];
        }       
        require MY_PLUGIN_DIR.'views/isotope.php';
    }
    add_shortcode('MY_GALLERY', 'my_shortcode');
}
add_action('init', 'my_shortcodes_init');
```

Comment: please any one here to explain or solve this issue i am newbie in wordpress plugin development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of the order of execution of your WordPress page. In your code it goes like this:

1. At `init`, which is early in the generation process of the page, you are registering the scripts. That is, you are telling WP that you want to use these later on. No html is generated.
2. At `init` you are also registering a shortcode. This means that you are defining a function that will be triggered once the shortcode has been encountered. No html is generated.
3. WP then goes on generating the html. First the head of the page, menus and so on, until it comes to the post content.
4. In the post content it finds the shortcode and starts executing the function `my_shortcode` you have defined. Inside this function it finds `wp_enqueue_script`. At this point the html of the head already has been generated. So it has no choice but placing the html with the scripts in the footer of the page.

If you want the scripts in the head, you must make sure `wp_enqueue_scripts` is triggered at `init`. Of course, this means they will also be enqueued when there is no shortcode in the content.

Comment: how can i enqueue those scripts and style only when shortcode encounter

Comment: great explaination ever...and it really worked .

Comment: but how can i restrict these scripts and style to load only when shortcode is encountered..

Comment: To do so, you would have to pre-run the post loop at `init`, check if the shortcode is present anywhere and if yes enqueue the scripts. This is possible, but fairly complicated stuff. If it's not essential that your scripts load in the head, I'd keep it the way it is now.

Comment: but i am using this code in plugin...how do i know where this shortcode will be used.

Comment: You don't know. That's why it's complicated stuff. You must think of all possible uses, try to track them down. Only if it's really necessary to have the script in the header you should follow this path. Otherwise, the footer is just fine.

Comment: its complicated i know...ohk let it be..

Answer (score 0):

The final argument in the `wp-enqueue-script` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) is a boolean which specifies whether the script should appear in the footer.

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

The first two scripts in your example do not specify the optional arguments, so it will default to `true`, putting the scripts down in the footer.

Comment: but those three in which i have mentioned those are also not loading in head

Comment: actually i have registered scripts first and loaded in shortcode so that these scripts can only be available if shortcode is applied.

Comment: hey i hvae described and added code of shortcode will you please try this for me...